# Convert CSS file classes into a string variable using webpack

Tags: css, angular, typescript, webpack

I have a CSS file containing multiple css classes in Angular project.I want to convert the css file classes into a string variable at compile time.so that I can assign it in my application at compile time only.Is there any way to achieve it? Like using webpack or some other solution

For Example-
I have test.css file-

.test-color{
color:red
}
.test-border{
border:1px
}

I want to convert this css file into a string like-
var convertedString= ".test-color{
color:red
}
.test-border{
border:1px
}"

this variable should be created at compile time,so that I can use this variable to pass it to CSSStyleSheet

Comment: You need to be more specific what exactly you want, give some examples of original file, desired output and how you would use it.

Comment: Updated the requirement  @BojanKogoj

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place ?

Comment: take a loom at  raw-loader which allows you to import files as a string

Comment: Hi @HezyZiv,Could you please suggest with an example? Also I to perform this at compile time only

Comment: check this example https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/